# GLM: Differing results for Interaction Effects depending on the link-function

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, gamma-distribution, link-function

I want to test whether whether a dispositional risk factors moderates the relation between a situational risk factor and a negative outcome in a regression model (including several control variables).

I found the moderation effect (predictor*moderator) in the expected direction using OLS Regression. However, the distribition of the criterion variable is heavily skewed and seems to be better described with a gamma distribution than with the gaussian form. Moreover, some requirements for OLS regression (Homoscedasticity, normal distribution of residuals) are not met.

Therefore, I calculated a generalized linear model with the glm-package in R, chosing "gamma" as the family-parameter. Since I was unsure about whether the moderation effect can be interpreted in a similar way when a non-linear "log"-link or "inverse"-link is used, I also calculated the same model with the "identity"-link, assuming that this ensures a "normal" interpretation of the predictor*moderator coefficient.

I printed fit-criteria for all 4 models (see image).

```
Model1: family = gaussian (link = "identity") = OLS
Model2: family = gamma (link = "identity")
Model3: family = gamma (link = "log")
Model4: family = gamma (link = "inverse")
```

[image]

The moderation coefficient is only significant in Model 1 and Model 2, but not in Model 3 and Model 4.

1. Is it justified to report the results for Model 2, since it seems to have the best fit-criteria? Or are there other important criteria I have to consider? My Moderation-Hypothesis was formulated in a linear way (I did not think about any potential non-linear relationship a priori).
2. Does the fact that I found no significant moderation coefficient in Model 3 and 4 weaken the evidence for my moderation-hypothesis? Would one expect consistent results across the different link-functions?

Comment: I don't think it is legitimate to compare these fit statistics for the different models.  The first 2 models have lower p-values, but I wouldn't want to make any decisions based on that, either.  I would look at plots of the data with the fitted functions and think about which modeling assumptions make sense in light of your data.  You could also try regressing a transformed Y variable (say, log Y) using OLS regression.  You need to use the model that is consistent with the nature of the data and situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hesitated to transform the Y variable since I read about that this could make the interpretation of interaction effects challenging. However, this is my main interest. Might it be appropriate to calculate an OLS regression and compare the results with models that are more robust against violations against non-normality of residuals (bootstrapping) and heteroscedasticity (robust estimators for standard errors)?

Comment: I don't know that the interpretation w/ a transformed variable is any more challenging than any of your other options.  I would be careful of simple bootstrapping routines with heteroscedasticity.  You need to figure out the model that makes sense given the nature of the data and the situation.  That can't really be done by us based on what you've put here.